# How to disable a particular safari extension settings item?

Tags: safari-extension

I am working on safari Plugin. How can I disable "Safari extension setting item" so that it will grayed out in "safari prefernces extension" window.

Comment: If you want to show a grayed-out preference in Safari's preferences window, there's no way to do that. But you can have a setting that does not appear in the preferences window. By creating settings properties programmatically instead of using the Extension Builder, you can have persistent settings that do not appear in the prefs window. To create a setting programmatically, in your global page script, use safari.extension.settings.setItem() to create it and safari.extension.settings.getItem() to read it. You can also access the safari.extension.settings object directly.

Comment: Thanks canisbos for the reply. But I want to display that setting in preferences window. Actually its enability depends on the value of other setting item. When it become enable I should be able to change it from preferences window itself.

Comment: I would suggest creating your own settings page. It's a lot more work, but you have complete control.